# How to know where an exception comes from?

Tags: java, exception, stream

I have implemented a run method for a parsing class, which handles a few input pipes with a while loop like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // do something
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException e) {

        closePorts();
        break;
    }
}
```

now, my problem is that I am handling more than one input streams, so I can't just close all ports on the first exception. I have to know which one of the input streams threw it and then close exactly that stream.

What is the best practice here? Is there a way to add that information to the exception itself? Do I have to send the information about which inputstream is throwing to the message as a String and then parse this String?

I want to do something like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // do something
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException e) {

        closePort(e.getIndexOfPort);    // something like this??
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Philipp

Comment: Err, write a separate `catch` block for I/O on each port?

Comment: Using an exception to find the end of a stream is bad practice, in general...See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: Handling the end of the stream is not an exceptional case. You should detect the end of stream inside the try-block. Exceptions are for exceptional cases and not for normal program flow.

Comment: @Rohan You frequently don't have any choice about it. There are many APIs in the JRE that are *designed* to throw `EOFException` at end of stream. There is precisely nothing you can do about that. The apparently widespread theory that 'exceptions should not be used for flow control' is a contradiction in terms. Exceptions *are* flow control: no two ways about it.

Comment: @FabianBarney Exceptions *are* flow control, and they are *essential* when an in-band return value isn't available, such as (for example) `DataInputStream.readInt()`. There is no possible return value here that could possibly express end of stream: so an exception is required.

Comment: Of course, Exceptions are flow control but for *exceptional* and not *normal* flow. Bad API design of classes like DataInputStream does not change that. In my opinion avoiding the use of that classes is the way to go then.

Comment: @FabianBarney So you've just redefined 'exceptional' to exclude everything that you don't think should be used for exceptions. This is just a circular argument. If you want to claim that `DataInputStream.readInt()` is badly designed, the onus is firmly on you to come up with a viable alternative, if you can, which you can't, for the reason I have already given; and recommending avoiding one of the most useful classes in the JRE doesn't count. This is all just ivory-tower attitudinizing that has no apparent connection with the real world.

Comment: @EJP: “no possible return value” is not a convincing reason for a software design. `readInt` could return a `long` instead. Note further that, e.g. `readUnsignedByte` also throws `EOFException` despite the returned `int` has room for special values. The actual reason is that `DataInput` is intended for parsing data formats where the absence of an expected value *is* an exceptional condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try-catch individual calls.

In the following example, `Input` is a fake class to illustrate the point, and `inputs` is a `List` of `Input` .

Note that the `break` statement will exit the `for` loop, you may need to break to a particular label to exit the while loop, or maybe return from your method.

```
while (true) {

            for (Input input : inputs) {

                try {

                        input.readSomething();

                } catch (EndOfStreamException e) {

                    closePort(input.getPort()); 
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: This is great. But now I feel stupid. I think for breaking my main loop I will have to count the exceptions and stop the filter if every port i closed?

Comment: You may check  that at least one of the `Input` in the list has an open port. If you don't find any, exit your main loop.